# Android: How to create a sequence of task

Tags: android, handler, runnable

Hello I'm a newbie for Android.

I writing a program to automate few tasks in sequence. In between each task, there will be a delay.
For example:

- Task 1: Vibrate phone for 5 seconds
- *Turn off vibration and delay for 2 seconds*
- Task 2: Open camera viewfinder for 5 seconds
- *Turn off viewfinder and delay for 2 seconds*

My question is, what is the proper method for the task above?

After some research, it seem like one proper way is to have a runnable inside a handler and postdelay **handler.postDelay(r)** to achieve the delay. But how to make sure task 2 is run after task1 is completed and delayed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

schedule the next task using `Handler.postdelayed` at the end of the previous task. For example

```
class Task1 implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        //perform task 1
        handler.postDelayed(new Task2(), 2000);
    }
}

class Task2 implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        //perform task 2
    }
}
```

now start the first task

```
    handler.post(new Task1());
```